# In SQL Query how to set table name

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use C#. I fill a dataset with the result of sql query. Suppose `ds` is my dataset:

```
Dataset ds = new Dataset();
ds = GetTablesFromDataBase("Select * from Order, Select * from OrderDetails, Select * from Product");
```

After running the code above, my dataset contains three tables named `Table`, `Table1`, `Table2`. But I want my dataset table names to be the same as database tables names like: `Order`, `OrderDetails`, `Product`. Is there any way to write query or code, so that dataset table names become the same as database table names?

Please, don't propose the code below to change the table names of a dataset:

```
Dataset.TableName = "RequiredTableName";
```

Comment: It is usually considered bad practice to select * from table: better practice is to list the specific columns required. Using * makes the application more fragile under change of the database schema.

Comment: chris walton thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use typed datasets or tablemapping

something like this

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(...);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTableMapping dtm1, dtm2, dtm3;
dtm1 = da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Employees"); 
dtm2 = da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Products");
dtm3 = da.TableMappings.Add("Table2", "Orders");
da.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use the DataTable class instead. Here is the mSDN reference for the same: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx
It lets you define all the properties that you want plus give you lot more functions to work with the table.

and since you seem to like having all the tables in one class I would suggest you create a DTO that basically resembles whatever property you wanted to use of the DataSet class and add IList as one of the properties of this DTO.

Hope that makes sense and helps you.

Answer (score 0):

`ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Required Table Name";`
`ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Required Table Name";`
`ds.Tables[2].TableName = "Required Table Name";`

You can use this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the names of the tables with an separate select.

```
SELECT 'Employees','Orders';
SELECT * FROM Employees;
SELECT * FROM Orders;
```

(you could also select the Tablenames from the global systemtables...)

Then you can set the Tablenames in your DataSet automatically:

```
for (int cIdx = 0; cIdx < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; ++cIdx) {
    int tIdx = cIdx + 1;
    if (tIdx >= ds.Tables.Count) {
        break;
    }
    ds.Tables[tIdx].TableName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][cIdx].ToString().Trim();
}
ds.Tables.RemoveAt[0];
```

This is also only a workaround, but I don't know a better way.